# Mostrar ou esconder uma imagem no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Eu estou fazer um aplicativo que lesse um valor, no caso (acesa ou apagada).

Com base nesse valor ele retornasse uma imagem. Se o valor fosse "acesa", o aplicativo me mostraria uma imagem de uma lâmpada acesa, e se o valor fosse "apagada", o aplicativo me mostraria uma imagem de uma lâmpada apagada.

Comment: Coloque um [mcve]. Qualquer dúvida leia [ask] ou então faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score 3):

## No xml, trabalhe as propriedades do componente:

Para deixar visível

```
  android:visibility="visible" :
```

Para deixar somente o espaço ocupado da imagem no xml, mas invisível:

```
 android:visibility="invisible"
```

Para remover a visibilidade do espaço ocupado e a imagem:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

## No código java, chame o método setVisibility:

Para deixar visível:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Para deixar somente o espaço ocupado da imagem no xml, mas invisível:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Para remover a visibilidade do espaço ocupado e a imagem:

```
 imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: bem completo, isso mesmo...

Answer (score 1):

Isso é questão de lógica de programação.

Pra deixar uma imagem visível use:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Pra deixar uma imagem invisível use:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que entendi bem a sua pergunta.

São duas imagens de uma lâmpada lado a lado. Quando uma esta acesa a outra tem que estar apagada. Se for bem isso então veja o código abaixo.

```
//Declare as variáveis;

private ImageView imgLampada1;

private ImageView imgLampada2;

//Recupere os ids no métodos onCreate da activity e configure as imagens das lampadas.

//Você também já deve ter as suas duas imagens (lampada_acesa.img e lampada_apagada.img) na sua pasta drawable.

imgLampada1 = findViewById(R.id.imgLampada1);

imgLampada2 = findViewById(R.id.imgLampada2);

//Configure as imagens nos ImageViews

imgLampada1.setImageResourse(R.drawable.lampada_acesa.img);

imgLampada2.setImageResourse(R.drawable.lampada_apagada.img);

//Crie os eventos de clicks dos dois imageViews acima.

imgLampada1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Quando clicakado apaga imgLampada1 e acende imgLampada2.

imgLampada1.setImageResourse(R.drawable.lampada_apagada.img);

imgLampada2.setImageResourse(R.drawable.lampada_acesa.img);


            }
        });


imgLampada1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Quando clicakado apaga imgLampada2 e acende imgLampada1.

imgLampada1.setImageResourse(R.drawable.lampada_acesa.img);

imgLampada2.setImageResourse(R.drawable.lampada_apagada.img);


            }
        });
```

Espero que de alguma forma isto ajude você. Se não, pode ajudar um outro alguém e fica de lição também.